# IRS (USA) Form 843 - What if you missed the three year deadline to file?

Tags: united-states, irs, income-tax-refund, amended-tax-return

I want to file 843 for a refund for my SS and Medicare taxes. I filed it on 3/30/2016. And it seems like I have missed the deadline [3/30/2019]. What are my options to claim the refund?